# Xampp manager on Mac OSX, recently the mysql server stopped starting

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I tried everything, changing the port no. and all but it still did not start I had to end the mysql process using the activity monitor and now the tables wont respond. When I click the name it shows an error message: #1146 table 'table_name' doesn't exist!
My past projects will be wasted if they don't respond and I had forgotten to export the databases.

Answer (score 0):

you can run this command to repair any database you have:

```
mysqlcheck -u mysql_username -p database_name
```

but if you see this error after running this:

```
Error: Table 'database_name.table_name' doesn't exist
```

you should drop your damaged table, all details can you find through this [link](http://www.linux.org/threads/resolving-mysql-error-1146-table-doesnt-exist-when-doing-backup.2480/)